# How to overlay a small page on a html page?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage underconstruction. I want to notify the people who visit it about its under-construction nature. For that I wanted to show a small transparent or transluscent page on the above page  as shown here http://img17.imageshack.us/i/normalpagewithasmallpag.png/

You may notice that i want that page to appear at the center of the webpage overlayed on the original page with a cross at top-right corner. Clicking on that cross may close this small page revealing the page behind it so that the users may see what has been developed so far.

I hope you guys have some suggestions for me. I know its possible with javascript but don't know how...any tutorial if available will also help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "under construction" is considered a bad practise (can not find reference for now)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after some sort of lightbox control...

Check this:

http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/

good luck

Comment: Aaaha..thats what i needed. Thanks a lot. :)

but how do i make one little amendment i.e. i want the webpage to show the overlayed page by default. In the example you gave  one has to click on the a link to generate a light box. How do i make that light box appear by default when i visit the page?

Comment: There appears to be some information on this here:

http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=212&page=1#Item_0

if not, take a look at BlockUI for jQuery as suggested by Kristoffer Deinoff

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in javascript with e.g. the jQuery framework. Check out [jQuery BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)